# Why is there a copper winding isolated from the iron core of my transformer?

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism

Here is a picture of a 1970's arc welding station.

There is a 9 inch bar of metal surrounded by 88 windings of 4mm copper, that used to be on the end of the secondary winding, which is made up of about 40 turns of 5mm copper.

What's it for?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's normally an inductor in series with the secondary (and a rectifier). That is probably the inductor.

There should also be a bar that slides through the slot in the transformer to adjust the welding current.

Comment: Thankyou, Yes i have the adjustment bar, it's actually oppositely wound screws that devide in the middle of the bar, each of which has a cube of laminated metal so that when you turn one one, the two cubes move towards and away from the centre of the transformer.

Comment: Aha! It is an attenuator / modulator. Some bass EQ knobs are like this: spin the knob and the core is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a choke (acts as flywheel to smooth rotation).

I think the (giant) rectifier diodes have been cut out?

Is that for AC or DC welding operation? Looks like AC without the rectifier but not sure why you would have a choke on AC. If it's AC there need not be diodes or rectifiers, just conductors.